# What is an SID and what happens if I remove it through sysprep?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, reset, sysprep

Let me start from the beginning:
So, this morning, I started my computer and my keyboard and mouse wouldn't respond. No big deal right? I'll just unplug and replug them in. No dice. I have since determined this is a problem with Windows 7 because:

- I can use my keyboard in the BIOS settings.
- I can use my mouse in the Windows 7 bootable usb.

My first thought was to repair windows without losing my files. However, I need to run the boot USB when I'm already in Windows 7 and, as I'm not able to login without a keyboard, this is not possible.
Now I want to reset my drivers, as I think that's the problem. I looked online and came across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/271575/remove-and-reinstall-all-drivers) post. It says to run `sysprep` to reset the drivers and the *SID*.

But... the SID? That sounds important. What happens if I reset it, will my PC not able to initialize due to a wrong security code? Is this even the correct way to resolve this program?

I am completely lost here and so any help is extremely appreciated...

Comment: Note: recognizing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), some users may try to solve the root issue and answer below. You should explicitly and in advance point them to [your other question](https://superuser.com/q/1561435/432690); and emphasize the current question is exactly "what is SID?".

Comment: DO NOT [`Sysprep`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation) your PC, as it's purpose is for deploying Windows to multiple machines, and is not going to solve your issue.  A SID is a [Security Identifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-identifiers). **General FYI: Windows 7 was EoL [End of Life] [as of 2020.01.14](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet)**, so it's no longer receiving Windows Updates, and is therefore no longer a secure OS to use.

Comment: @JW0914 Hmm okay, then I'll have to find another way... Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Lapraniteon Clean installing Windows 10 would be recommended, as Windows 7 should no longer be used.

Comment: @JW0914 That is the plan then, although I'm not certain over how good it will run on a PC from 2010, but it seems there's no other option besides Linux (which I don't want). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lapraniteon Age of the PC doesn't matter, CPU & RAM would. Win10 has a "smart" installer, adjusting what to install, and services to configure, depending on hardware specs of the machine it's being installed on. If the PC has <16GB RAM and <=4 CPU cores (logical or physical), I'd recommend Ubuntu, as it'll run quite a bit better due to Windows' heavy reliance on resource-hungry services. You can run Windows programs on Linux via [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), and overall wouldn't notice that large of a user experience difference with an OS like [Ubuntu Desktop.](https://ubuntu.com/desktop)